# Install TWIG template engine stand alone, without composer

Tags: php, templates, twig

I want to install and use [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/installation.html) as in a module and I copied the contents of the /lib/twig/ contents to to a folder called /twig in my modules folder. I've in put require_once('twig/Autoloader.php'); at the top of my module and I use Twig_Autoloader::register() to try and get it work but as soon as I use

```
$this->loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($path);
$this->twig = new Twig_Environment($this->loader, array(
    //options
));
```

And I get this error:
Fatal error: Class 'Twig_Loader_Filesystem' not found in

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Sorry can you show me where you get `$path` from

Comment: I had to dig a little, I had those variables build up from the root + the layout folder. But I don't remember what those were, its been a while.

Comment: No worries. I managed to get up and running with this in the end > https://github.com/marvin/php-twig-example :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rename your `twig` folder to `Twig`, and then change your include:

```
require_once('Twig/Autoloader.php');
```

It should work now.